# foreach loop to fetch JSON value

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I am trying to fetch all the latitude and longitude of my JSON result.

JSON Result (have many records):

```
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 28.637255,
           "lng" : 77.05202800000001
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
     "id" : "aef56d078ec3fcab6f4a966bd944d3d59973bd72",
     "name" : "Homeopati Kendra",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : false,
        "weekday_text" : []
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJQavdFRwFDTkRMRAhjCbIOnI",
     "reference" : "CnRjAAAAwCoBEGDvsL4KeQNPyT2OsVF82b7FChIpUHRFQvGg8b1eR7FCv9I1nUPn0lFf50OVG9ug1PevkcZG813Lq9AAe1dK5GCgn99ajpQ1it9lafCwX3SaUwtiinLiepgptdHNz3NgDzhpVIx70a2D1KZcchIQvD4OS73_Jmr2wYQg4jtRjxoUjCnGT2M4XzDIXadJOtgA-LgRNR4",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "types" : [ "hospital", "health", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "C-29 , Vikas Nagar,Uttam Nagar, Vikas Nagar Extn, Hastsal, New Delhi"
  },
```

for particular record (say record first):

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(googleResult);
JArray jarr = (JArray)obj["results"];
double lt = (double)jarr[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
double lg = (double)jarr[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
```

for fetching all records:

```
foreach(var item in jarr)
{
double lt = Convert.ToDouble(item[jarr["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]]);
}
```

For fetching one record it works fine but for all records its not working.

Comment: Change your line to be `double lt = Convert.ToDouble(jarr[item]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]);`.

Comment: [`Convert.ToDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) assumes the input string is in the current thread culture.  You should probably use a culture-invariant method such as the [`JToken` explicit cast](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_26.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to pick out the fields of interest from your JSON.  Since this method supports [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) you can use the `"*"` wildcard to loop through all entries in the `"results"` array:

```
        var locations = JToken.Parse(googleResult)
            .SelectTokens("results[*].geometry.location")
            .Select(t => new { Lat = (double)t["lat"], Lng = (double)t["lng"] })
            .ToList();
```

Or, if you prefer a `foreach` loop:

```
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(googleResult);
        JArray jarr = (JArray)obj["results"];
        foreach (var item in jarr)
        {
            double lt = (double)item.SelectToken("geometry.location.lat");
            double lg = (double)item.SelectToken("geometry.location.lng");
        }
```